# Is it possible to decipher at random position with nodejs crypto?

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes, random-access, node-crypto

My understanding is that an AES block cipher in CTR mode allows, in theory, to decipher any location of a large file, without needing to read the whole file.

However, I don't see how to do this with nodejs crypto module. I could feed the `Decipher.update` method with dummy blocks until I get to the part I'm interested in, at which point I would feed actual data read from the file, but that would be an awful hack, inefficient, and fragile, since I need to be aware of the block size.

Is there a way to do it with the crypto module, and if not, what module can I use?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, if you can calculate numbers stored in a `Buffer` for advancing the IV. Also, the block size is fixed to 16 bytes if you're using AES.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Are you referring to the "solution" of repeatedly calling `Decipher.update` with dummy data? I really don't think that's a good method. Let's say I have a 1TB file, and I just want to read a few MB from it, near the end. I don't want to compute 1TB worth of cipher blocks just to finally decipher a few MB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found different approaches to solve this problem:

### Method 1 : CTR mode

This answer is based on @ArtjomB. and @gusto2 comments and answer, which really gave me the solution. However, here is a new answer with a working code sample, which also shows implementation details (for example the IV must be incremented as a Big Endian number).

The idea is simple: to decrypt starting at an offset of `n` blocks, you just increment the IV by `n`. Each block is 16 bytes.

```
import crypto = require('crypto');
let key = crypto.randomBytes(16);
let iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);

let message = 'Hello world! This is test message, designed to be encrypted and then decrypted';
let messageBytes = Buffer.from(message, 'utf8');
console.log('       clear text: ' + message);

let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-ctr', key, iv);
let cipherText = cipher.update(messageBytes);
cipherText = Buffer.concat([cipherText, cipher.final()]);

// this is the interesting part: we just increment the IV, as if it was a big 128bits unsigned integer. The IV is now valid for decrypting block n°2, which corresponds to byte offset 32
incrementIV(iv, 2); // set counter to 2

let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-ctr', key, iv);
let decrypted = decipher.update(cipherText.slice(32)); // we slice the cipherText to start at byte 32
decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);
let decryptedMessage = decrypted.toString('utf8');
console.log('decrypted message: ' + decryptedMessage);
```

This program will print:

```
       clear text: Hello world! This is test message, designed to be encrypted and then decrypted
decrypted message: e, designed to be encrypted and then decrypted
```

As expected, the decrypted message is shifted by 32 bytes.

And finally, here is the incrementIV implementation:

```
function incrementIV(iv: Buffer, increment: number) {
    if(iv.length !== 16) throw new Error('Only implemented for 16 bytes IV');

    const MAX_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    let incrementBig = ~~(increment / MAX_UINT32);
    let incrementLittle = (increment % MAX_UINT32) - incrementBig;

    // split the 128bits IV in 4 numbers, 32bits each
    let overflow = 0;
    for(let idx = 0; idx < 4; ++idx) {
        let num = iv.readUInt32BE(12 - idx*4);

        let inc = overflow;
        if(idx == 0) inc += incrementLittle;
        if(idx == 1) inc += incrementBig;

        num += inc;

        let numBig = ~~(num / MAX_UINT32);
        let numLittle = (num % MAX_UINT32) - numBig;
        overflow = numBig;

        iv.writeUInt32BE(numLittle, 12 - idx*4);
    }
}
```

### Method 2 : CBC mode

Since CBC uses the previous *cipher text* block as IV, and that all cipher text blocks are known during the decryption stage, you don't have anything particular to do, you can decrypt at any point of the stream. The only thing is that the first block you decrypt will be garbage, but the next ones will be fine. So you just need to start one block before the part you actually want to decrypt.

Comment: nice..   imho the `incrementIV` looks too complicated for me (I am using Java witch has native tools for this), but seems you made it working,  good job

Comment: @gusto2 Sure, it may be possible to simplify it, and/or make it more readable. However, there is no native functionality in javascript to handle numbers bigger than 32 bits (actually, all numbers are double precision floating point, which can only encode integers up to 50bits or something like that). There are libraries such as "bigint" and "bignum", but I don't like adding too much dependencies, when all I need fits in 10 lines of code... I've tested this function in various cases (including overflow and cycle back to zero) and I think it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

> I could feed the Decipher.update method with dummy blocks until I get to the part I'm interested in

As @Artjom already commented,  assuming using CTR mode, you don't need to feed start of the file or any dummy blocks. You can directly feed ciphertext you are interested in. (starting the blocksize of 128 bit using AES)

see the [CTR mode of operation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation), you just need to set the IV counter to the starting block of the ciphertext,  feed only part of the encrypted file you want to decipher (you may need to feed dummy bytes of the starting block if needed)

Example:

you need to decrypt a file from position 1048577,   using AES it's block 65536 (1048577/16) plus 1 byte. So you set the IV to `nonce|65536`, decrypt dummy 1 byte (to move to position to 16*65536+1) and then you can just feed your ciphertext from the part of the file you are interested in

Comment: OK, so I did not understand what @ArtjomB. said :-/ I think I understand better now what he, and you, meant. I'm still not sure about the IV format, do you mean to concatenate the random IV with the counter? How many bytes for each, what endianness for the counter, which comes first, etc?

Comment: @youen depending how IV is constructed. IV is 128 bit byte array. The wikipedia describes the CTR IV as nonce concatenated with counter (64bit +64bit) . Most common I see IV  randomly initialized (nobody said the counter must start from 0)then you just add the block count to the binary representation of initial IV value

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm. I didn't mean to steal your answer, but posted one with a working code sample, as I think it can help other people with the same issue, as it's more precise.